# Entity Framework Code First - map same entity twice for different purpose

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I have two models, One `ApplicationUser` which holds all users in the system and I have a Quotation model which will hold all `Quotations` made. now I want to store two mappings to `ApplicationUser` inside `Quotations`. So that I can map to created User as well as cancelled User. My model looks like this

```
    public class Quotation
{
    public int QuotationID { get; set; }
    public DateTime QuotationDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime QuotationCancelDate { get; set; }
    public int ApplicationUserID { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser CreatedUser { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ApplicationUserID")]
    public ApplicationUser CancelledUser { get; set; }

}
```

But this throws an error

```
Quotation_CancelledUser_Target_Quotation_CancelledUser_Source: : The types of all properties in the Dependent Role of a referential constraint must be the same as the corresponding property types in the Principal Role. The type of property 'ApplicationUserID' on entity 'Quotation' does not match the type of property 'Id' on entity 'ApplicationUser' in the referential constraint 'Quotation_CancelledUser'.
```

So I guess , The approach I am taking is wrong. Can anyone point out the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: try changing ApplicationUserID to ApplicationUserId ? in both properties and foreign key attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are observing is called "Multiple Cascade Path". A Multiple Cascade Path happens when a cascade path goes from column col1 in table A to table B and also from column col2 in table A to table B.

The exception is caused by SQL Server when code first attempted to add table that has columns appearing more than once of another table.

In SQL Server, a table cannot appear more than one time in a list of all the cascading referential actions that are started by either a DELETE or an UPDATE statement. For example, the tree of cascading referential actions must only have one path to a particular table on the cascading referential actions tree.

You will need to use FluentAPI to configure the relationship. I am using EF5 currently and do not know if this can be accomplished in EF6/7.

So modifying your code sample, it would look like:

```
public class Quotation
{
    public int QuotationID { get; set; }
    public DateTime QuotationDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime QuotationCancelDate { get; set; }

    public int CreatedUserID { get; set; }
    // Navigation property
    public virtual ApplicationUser CreatedUser { get; set; }

    public int CancelledUserID { get; set; }
    // Navigation property
    public virtual ApplicationUser CancelledUser { get; set; }
}

// Created a simple class for example
public class ApplicationUser
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now in you context class you can write:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //  Disable the default PluralizingTableNameConvention
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

        // Add configuration here

        modelBuilder.Entity<Quotation>()
            .HasKey(e => e.QuotationID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
            .HasKey(e => e.Id);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Quotation>()
                        .HasRequired(a => a.CreatedUser)
                        .WithMany()
                        .HasForeignKey(u => u.CreatedUserID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Quotation>()
            .HasRequired(a => a.CancelledUser)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(u => u.CancelledUserID);
    }
```

For more information with example refer this [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-5-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations).

Comment: Now it causes another error.Quotation_CancelledUser_Target_Quotation_CancelledUser_Source: : The types of all properties in the Dependent Role of a referential constraint must be the same as the corresponding property types in the Principal Role. The type of property 'CancelledUserID' on entity 'Quotation' does not match the type of property 'Id' on entity 'ApplicationUser' in the referential constraint 'Quotation_CancelledUser'.
Quotation_CreatedUser_Target_Quotation_CreatedUser_Source: :

Comment: The types of all properties in the Dependent Role of a referential constraint must be the same as the corresponding property types in the Principal Role. The type of property 'CreatedUserID' on entity 'Quotation' does not match the type of property 'Id' on entity 'ApplicationUser' in the referential constraint 'Quotation_CreatedUser'.

Comment: Use .HasForeignKey(u => u.CreatedUserID).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

Comment: @Athul - EF Version? I am using EF5 and the above code is working fine.

Comment: Athul, I just checked. The above code works with EF6 as well with no changes. I think you are getting error due to incorrect key configuration in your set up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71557/discussion-between-sbirthare-and-athul).